# camera error in qt

Tags: qt, camera, qt-mobility, n97

I want to use camera functionality on my application.

I have built this functionality using the following link:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/camera.html#still-images

But when I run on my Nokia N97 device using USB cable it create an error

```
[Qt Message] Camera error: "Starting viewfinder failed." 
[Qt Message] Camera error: "Starting viewfinder failed." 
[Qt Message] Camera error: "Starting viewfinder failed." 
[Qt Message] Camera error: "Starting viewfinder failed." 
[Qt Message] Camera error: "Starting viewfinder failed."
```

I also remembering you that this work in first time but then it create an error

So what is the real problem
I install qt.sis,qtmobility.sis,tkr,webtoolkit in my n97 device

Comment: Which version of QtMobility are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version is 1.2 (released May 12th) and there where several bug fixes since 1.01. Including one bugfix in 1.1.2 which fixed an error concerning the "Starting viewfinder failed." issue, especially when using QVideoRendererControl. See [this bug report](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTMOBILITY-1315) for more information.

Maybe you should update your libs and see if the error still exists.